# CSS font-face does not load on PhoneGap application

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I implemented an application in Android with PhoneGap. So UI is implemented with jQuery Mobile.
I used CSS font-face for giving custom font to application texts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url("../fonts/MyFont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    src: url("../fonts/MyFont.otf") format("opentype");
}
body {
    font-family: MyFont;
}
```

But when I install the application on Android, texts are shown by default font face.

How can I solve this problem in Android?

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct syntax that works on android phones:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yanone';
    src: url('fonts/yanone/YanoneKaffeesatz-Regular-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('fonts/yanone/YanoneKaffeesatz-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/yanone/YanoneKaffeesatz-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('fonts/yanone/YanoneKaffeesatz-Regular-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You should also be careful about relative path to your custom font.